# XMPP XEP-0198 not working in eJabberd version 2.1.10

Tags: xmpp, stream-management

is there any way to enable XEP-0198 or stream management in ejabberd version 2.1.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That version is 4 years old and it appears XEP-0198 support was merged [last year](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/pull/166), so no.

Comment: Thanks for quick response...Now then only thing i see is we have to migrate ejabberd server to current latest version 15.11